# My question doesn't appear on my profile

Tags: support, user-accounts, questions

I asked [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29430/is-there-a-latex-symbol-for-order/29492) before I joined the site (not sure how I could do that, but I did). The question shows my name and avatar on it, but it does not appear in my profile under questions. How can I fix that?

Comment: I've flagged the older question so that a moderator can merge your two accounts.

Answer (score 8):

You had two accounts, one unregistered. I have merged them: you should now have full control of the older question.